# Some Images is not shown when upload by mobile in django application but work always perfectly when upload throw laptop?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am stuck in the very serious problem without any solution. This is my models.py file

```html
class Report_item(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='*Title for the post e.g. item identity')
    item_type = models.CharField(default="", max_length=100,
                                 help_text='*Enter the item name you found e.g. Marksheet,key,wallet')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=60, help_text='*Enter the address/street where you find this item')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60, help_text='*Enter the city name')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    Description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True,help_text='*Enter full description about item')
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    image = models.FileField(default="add Item image",
                             help_text='*Please uplocad a item image to identify by the owner')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + "      " + str(self.publish)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('feed:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-date"]
```

When I upload an image from my laptop then it is uploaded successfully and also shown in the feed. But when I uploaded using a mobile phone then it always uploads but does not show in feed or profile page. Although the image with the same name is available in admin panel but when I try to open it then it shows the 404 not found an error.

Comment: How do you upload your images through mobile? Can you add the corresponding views?

Comment: I host my application on EC2. So upload a picture using mobile phone cause me an error or image not found but no error found when using a laptop

Comment: can you add the error tracback?

Comment: It is giving 403 Forbidden on images upload by using a mobile phone.

Comment: It's permission denied. Please add the corresponding view class and error traceback?